# Converting multiple sequences to subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

An exercise on my textbook is giving me a fair bit of trouble, mainly because I don't know if changing the index of more of one sequence to "fit the bill" is valid. This sounds weird, but below it will become clearer:

Suppose $A$, $B$ are closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $\exists x_n\in A$, $\exists y_n \in B$ such that $||x_n -y_n||\leq \frac1n$. The goal is to prove that if $A$ or $B$ are limited, then $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$.

My attempt at proving this is as such: I supposed $A$ is limited (because the $B$ case is analogous) and concluded $A$ is compact. Therefore, by definition of compact every sequence in $A$ has a subsequence that is convergent to a limit point in $A$ (the subsequence being $x_{n_k}$, and its limit $x$). Therefore (and this is the step that I'm not sure is valid) we have $||x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}||\leq\frac1{n_k}$. Then we have $y_{n_k}\to x$ as $n_k \to \infty$, and $y_{n_k}$ has the same limit as $x_{n_k}$. So, the sequences have the same limit point; since both $A$ and $B$ are closed, they contain all their limit points and $A\cap B$ cannot be $\emptyset$.

The $B$ limited and both $A$ and $B$ limited cases are analogous.

The possible flaw I see in the argument is that changing $||x_n -y_n||\leq \frac1n$ to $||x_{n_k}-y_{n_k}||\leq\frac1{n_k}$ might not be valid. Can anyone clarify why I can do this, or why I can't and fix my proof (which doesn't seem to be completely incorrect at least)?

Comment: $|x_m - y_m|\le \frac{1}{m}$, for _all_ $m$ (in other words, it holds for every subscript $m$). The indices $n_k$ are just being used as subscripts, so there's no issue.

Comment: By the way, the English terminology is "bounded", not "limited".

Comment: Thanks! The part that didn't sound right is that changing $y_n$ to $y_{n_k}$ feels quite "arbitrary", unnatural. I don't know how to explain it. The language barrier is real.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the problem statement is ambiguous, since you have a free variable $n$ that you neither quantify over nor define, so it's not clear whether $\exists x_n\in A.\exists y_n\in B.\|x_n-y_n\|\le\frac1n$ holds for some $n$ or for all $n$. However, the more natural interpretation is clearly that $\forall n$ is implied. In this case, your proof is valid, since you're applying a universal statement that holds for all $n$ to particular values of $n$.